# Change file permission without being a superuser

Tags: c++, c, linux

I want to read some files, which are coming from a third party tool, in a directory. Before reading those files I am checking that if those are `regular file`.

bofore reading

```
if (!S_ISREG(file_info.st_mode))
{
    return false;
}
```

after reading this file I want to change it`s permission so that it will not read again and again.

My question is How could I change file permission `st_mode` so that my application will not read it again without being a superuser.

My linux distro is RedHat

Comment: Who is the owner of the files?

Comment: from a third party tool those files are generated. I am just reading files.so I am not the owner of those files.

Comment: Tools don't own files. A file is owned by a user… so the question becomes "what user was that tool running as?". @hek2mgl is leading to: if you don't have ownership, you cannot make the change (unless you're the root user).

Comment: @mah... Is there any way so that I can stop to read that file again. Thanks for you clarification.

Comment: @hek2mgl... If I own those file how can I change those permissions?

Comment: @user2845185 mcleod_ideafix gave the proper answer

Comment: Changing the file permission is generally not the right way to avoid reading a file again. Usually, your tool would have some data where it remembers what it has read or, in the case of a synchronization-like tool, it would detect that the candidate source file is older than the corresponding destination file. If neither of those is suitable, it would generally be preferable to set some other metadata on the source file rather than changing its permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the file and don't want to read it again, you shouldn't test if it is a regular file, because no matter the permissions it has, a regular file is a regular file. So I think you should check for read permission, and if it is set, read the file, and use `chmod()` to set permissions to disable reading.

```
/* Check it it is readable by the user */
if ((file_info.st_mode & S_IRUSR)==0)
{
  return false;
}

/* If it is, open and read the file... */
...
...

/* Mark it as not readable by the user. file_name is assumed
   to be the name of the file as you have used it upon calling
   lstat */
chmod (file_name, file_info.st_mode & ~S_IRUSR);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are the owner of the files ( may be you are the owner if you are running the third party tool) you can directly use chmod command from terminal to change the permissions of the file. 
"**Ex : chmod 666 log.txt**" 
 No need to use sudo before the chmod.

Comment: when that file is running on server I can not go there to open terminal... This logically.

Comment: The same thing you can put on a simple c program. :-)